# Rows alternate in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have this query.

```
Select name from Table
```

and this is the result.

[image]

Now, I need this risult.

[image]

This is the question. How can I modify the query for write 'OK' after every  single row ?

Thank you

Comment: Do this at the application layer.  It is painful to do in MS Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
Select [name], 1 As S, [name] As Ex
From Table;
Union All
Select [name], 2 As S, "OK" As Ex
From Table
Order By 1, 2
```

The last column will hold your sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much